# Give an example of a nonconstant function f from poset A to poset B which is simultaneously increasing and decreasing.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm also asked to show that no such function exists if A is totally ordered.

I have no clue how to do this; how can a function even be simultaneously increasing and decreasing?

Thank you!

Comment: What are your definitions of increasing and decreasing for functions on posets?

Comment: Let the partialorder on $A$ be represented as $\preceq_A$ and the partialorder on $B$ be represented as $\preceq_B$.  I assume that by "increasing function" you mean a function where if $a_1\preceq_A a_2$ then $f(a_1)\preceq_B f(a_2)$, and by "decreasing function" you mean a function where if $a_1\preceq_A a_2$ then $f(a_2)\preceq_B f(a_1)$.  Assuming this is the case, then as for a hint for an example... think about vacuous truths and/or remember that equality is a partial order.  For the second part, remember that the function should be nonconstant and remember orders are antisymmetric.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, that's clever. I'm not sure that your hint for the first part will be easy to follow though.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a <= b in A.  Then for such a function f,
f(a) <= f(b) <= f(a) and equality ensues.

This shows for linearily ordered A, f is constant.

Now let A = B = {a, b, c, d} be ordered by a < b, s < t.
Map s,t to t and a,b to b for a nonconstant function that
is both increasing and decreasing.

It's a got ya acoming an' a going function.
Clearly increasing means ascending (not strictly increasing).